# Specify Destination Directory for 'zip' Command Output (The Zip file that is Created)

Tags: linux, unix, zip

The zip command generally places the output zip file in the current directory. But, I'm wondering if there is an option that I'm overlooking in the man page that lets me specify the destination directory for the output archive file.

This created 'my_archive' in the current directory:

```
zip -rT my_archive dir_to_be_archived
```

But, I want to be able to place 'my_archive' under ./my_backups without having to 'cd' into that backups directory. Is there something like:

```
zip -rt my_archive dir_to_be_archived --destination ./my_backups
```

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140960/how-to-zip-a-file-and-save-it-in-another-directory

Comment: not implying dupe, there is no dupe across sites

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can specify the destination path directly:

```
zip -r /path/to/destination.zip /files
```

Keep in mind that the destination should *not* be in the same directory as the files that you are zipping up.

Comment: It appears to require the path to exist - is it possible to have it created as part of the command?

Comment: @Jeppe you can easily create it with `mkdir -p /path/to && zip ...`

Comment: Adjecent to this question, relative directories also work. `zip -r ../app.zip .` will put files in the current directory in a .zip in the parent.